# Display distance on x-axis of google maps elevation chart

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Does any of you know of a simple way to add distance on the X-axis of the Google maps elevation chart example (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths)?

I have seen several entries here on SO about this but none has a working answer referring to a JSFiddle or similar.

Thanks in advance for any input!

Regards

/Peter

Answer (score 1):

I created a simplified solution that uses the code provided by Google accompanied with some minor modifications that assign distance to each column based on the total distance divided by the amount of columns. See modified excerpt from the sample code below;

```
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Distance');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Height');
    for (var i = 0; i < elevations.length; i++) {
      data.addRow([Math.round(((totalDistance/amountOfColumns)*i)) + " m",elevations[i].elevation]);
    }

    // Draw the chart using the data within its DIV.
    chart.draw(data, {
      height: 150,
      legend: 'Height profile',
      titleY: 'Height (m)',
      titleX: 'Distance (m)',
      hAxis: {
          title: 'Distance (m)',
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Height (m)'
        },
      colors: ['#000000']
    });
  }
```